# Resizing .tex Table in Rmarkdown Beamer Slides

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc, beamer

**Problem:**

Regression tables need to be shrunk to include in Beamer slides, but cannot shrink them in RMarkdown without copy and pasting the raw TeX. Is there an easier way to do this so I can automate this part of my workflow?

**Background**

My regressions automatically generate .tex files for regression tables. However, when I try to input the files into my Beamer slides (created in Rmarkdown), they are too big and I have to manually copy, paste, and resize them to make them fit. Below is an MWE

**table.tex**

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
  \caption{Title}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Var} \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 Independent Var & $-$0.031 & 0.012 & $-$0.264 & $-$0.267 & $-$0.107 & $-$1.980 \\
\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{6}{l}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

**RMarkdown.Rmd**

```
---
title: "Title"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 3
    keep_tex: false
---

### Test Results
\input{table.tex}
```

**Workaround**

Copy/paste .tex table and add `\resizebox{}{}` surrounding `\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}`

**Workaround.Rmd**

```
---
title: "Title"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 3
    keep_tex: false
---

### Test Results
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
  \caption{Title}

\resizebox{0.98\textwidth}{!}{

\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\\[-1.8ex]\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Var} \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
 Independent Var & $-$0.031 & 0.012 & $-$0.264 & $-$0.267 & $-$0.107 & $-$1.980 \\
\hline
\hline \\[-1.8ex]
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{6}{l}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\
\end{tabular}

}

\end{table}
```

Comment: What about adding `\small` before `\input{table.tex}` and `\normalsize` after?

Comment: That helps but I would like to be able to have control over the dimensions rather than hope it shrinks it appropriately.

Comment: When you run the regressions, can you cache (or in some other way save in an R-readable format) the output object at the point just before generating the latex markup. Then load this object into your rmarkdown-beamer document and generate the latex within the beamer document. That way, you can customize the table within the rmarkdown workflow. For example, say you've saved a regression model object. Load it into the rmarkdown-beamer doc, then run `kable`, `xtable`, `stargazer` or whatever on it to produce the latex table in a beamer-slide-suitable size.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that because I'm running regressions on relatively large datasets. For one of my tables, the regression object is 1.1Gb, so I would prefer to just preserve the .tex output (1.6kb) instead.

Comment: I'm not sure how your creating the regression tables, but you might just need to cache the summary output. For example, if you create an `lm` model (let's call the model object `m1`) then `summary(m1)` produces an object with the coefficients, p-values, standard errors, R-squared, etc. Basically, just cache what you need to produce the regression table. You don't need the full model object.

Comment: `kable`, `xtable`, and `stargazer` do not work with summary objects as far as I can tell, unfortunately.

Comment: For `stargazer` tables, I have used the following: `begin{table}[!htbp]\centering\tiny` then the knitr chunk generating the stargazer table, and then `end{table}`. I think you have to twiddle some stargazer options to not print the table environment. I think `float=FALSE` will do it.

Comment: `stargazer` also has a `font.size` option, but it will not work well in Beamer, say.

Answer (score 2):

Scaling elements which contain text can result in a sub-optimal readability of the text. Instead you could use the `fitting` library from the `tcolorbox` package to automatically choose a suitable font size:

```
---
title: "Title"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 3
    keep_tex: false
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{tcolorbox}
 - \tcbuselibrary{fitting}
---

### Test Results 
\begin{tcolorbox}[fit,width=\textwidth,height=.9\textheight,size=minimal,colback=white,fit algorithm=fontsize,colframe=white]
  \input{table.tex}
\end{tcolorbox}
```